# How to get data from JSON after decode

Tags: php, json, decode

From API i get following JSON string

```
{  
   "cost":1000.00,
   "cost_ua":25900.44,
   "pay_date":"29-07-2017",
   "payments":{  
      "1":{  
         "tar":"90965",
         "name":"Ввозная ( импортная ) пошлина",
         "basis_value":25900.44,
         "sum_type":"грн.",
         "pay_description":{  
            "name":"Льготная/полная",
            "value":"5.00 %",
            "comments":"ЗУ N 584-VII",
            "document":{  
               "num":"584-VII",
               "date":"19-09-2013"
            }
         }
      },
      "2":{ "name":"Налог на добавленную стоимость ( НДС )" }
   },
   "payments_sum":6734.11,
   "payments_ua_sum":260.00,
   "payments_persent":26.00
}
```

After json_decode how can i get "basis_value" and "comments" ?
I tried this, but it not work

```
$result_parse = json_decode($response);

echo $result_parse->payments->basis_value;
echo $result_parse->payments->1->basis_value;
```

Comment: Can you try `$result_parse->payments->{'1'}->basis_value` ?

Comment: As `1` is not a legal variable name in PHP you have to use `echo $j->payments->{1}->basis_value;`

Comment: It would be a better idea to correct the code that creates this json string

Comment: @u_mulder This issue is a little different to the normal JSON extraction issues if you look a little closer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
echo $result_parse->payments->{'1'}->basis_value;
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f39731b67fb7732ab0085b331762edc1665a987)

Comment: That works, I have tested it. But I had already answered that.

Comment: It's Ok, I got late to do answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way: `$array->payments->{1}->basis_value`
I have **tested** in  [Php Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/). I hope it helps.

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$array = json_decode('{  
   "cost":1000.00,
   "cost_ua":25900.44,
   "pay_date":"29-07-2017",
   "payments":{  
      "1":{  
         "tar":"90965",
         "name":"Ввозная ( импортная ) пошлина",
         "basis_value":25900.44,
         "sum_type":"грн.",
         "pay_description":{  
            "name":"Льготная/полная",
            "value":"5.00 %",
            "comments":"ЗУ N 584-VII",
            "document":{  
               "num":"584-VII",
               "date":"19-09-2013"
            }
         }
      },
      "2":{ "name":"Налог на добавленную стоимость ( НДС )" }
   },
   "payments_sum":6734.11,
   "payments_ua_sum":260.00,
   "payments_persent":26.00
}');
echo print_r($array->payments->{1}->basis_value,1);
```